# Gram-Schmidt Process.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this question on as problem set.

Find an orthonormal basis for M2x2(R) by applying the Gram-Schmidt process to the basis.

{$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$}

I have denoted them $V_1,V_2,V_3V_4$ respectively.  But I can't seem to make $V_2$ orthogonal to $V_1$.  (P.S, to find the norm of a matrix to you square each coeffiecnet of the matrix, add them together, then take the squareroot? Such that $||V_1||=\sqrt{{1^2} + {0^2} + {0^2} +{0^2}}=\sqrt{1}=1$

$V_2'=V_2 - <V_2, V_1>.V_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}-Trace\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}-1.\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}.$

Where $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\sqrt{2}\\-1\sqrt{2}&0\end{bmatrix}$ is the normalized matrix of $V_2'.$  Would continuing with $V_3, V_4$ lead to the correct basis?

Comment: How is your inner product defined?

Comment: $<A,B>=Trace(A^TB)$

Comment: Your $V_2' $ is off.

Comment: Thanks, I had the Trace as a matrix and multiplied $V_1$ instead of finding the scalar of the Trace,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your scalar product writes

$$(X,Y) = X:Y = \sum_{i,j}X_{ij}Y_{ij}=tr (X^TY),$$

Then we have by definition of Gram-Schmidt process

$$V_2' = V_2 - \frac{(V_2,V_1)V_1}{\|V_1\|^2} = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix} - \frac{\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}}{1+0+0+0}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Note that $V_2'$ is already normalised.

Then you can say that $$V_3' = V_3 -  (V_3,V_1)V_1  -  (V_3,V_2' )V_2',$$
renormalise $V_3'$, write a similar formula for $V_4'$, etc.